# PDF generated is blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
 private static void DownloadFile()
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            WebResponse webResponse;
            GetTheResponseFromFTP(out reqFTP, out webResponse, true);

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)webResponse;

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter =
                  new StreamWriter("d:\\TestUnity.pdf", true))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }


            reader.Close();
            response.Close();  
        }
```

I have the above function, that download a file from the FTP location. 
I am reading the text and trying to write it in a file in my local machine.
The PDf file generated is of the same size as it is downloaded but when I open the file its blank. Now I have two questions:

1. Can any one suggest how to save the downloaded file to a path which can be changed.
2. Whats the reason for the above problem mentioned.

Comment: You haven't made a pdf, you've made a textfile with a pdf extension (try opening it in notepad)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx).

> [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) implements a TextWriter for writing characters to a stream

This means you haven't created a pdf file but a textfile with the *.pdf extension.

There are multiple utilities available to create a pdf

[WkHtmlToPDF](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) are just two

Comment: Can you suggest is this the right way to download a file from ftp.? If not then please help how to download file. Code on net is available but I am not getting where does the downloaded file is saved. So plz guide.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple code which works for me

```
    void GeneratePDF(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (var streamFile = File.Create("E:/JSS.pdf"))
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(streamFile);
    }
```